# Creating a small database of DC bikeshare locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, screen-scraping

I'm kind of new to this site and programming in general, so please excuse me if I say something incorrectly.

I need to find a list of all the latitude-longitude locations of the bikeshare kiosks in DC. The map with all the stations can be found [here](http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/station_map). Basically I can't figure out how to do this without manually going in, finding where exactly the kiosk is on the map on the bikeshare website, and then locating it through google maps to find the lat/long (I found out that this can be done by right clicking on the location in google maps). I've searched long and hard to see if there is a database somewhere that has stored this information, or if I can get it from the bikeshare site directly, but I can't find it anywhere.

I can do it for the DC metro station by clicking on the map directly (like [here](http://www.wmata.com/rail/station_detail.cfm?station_id=25), if you click on the map, you can see a google maps page pop up with the lat/long location).

This is my first time using the Google Maps API. I want to be able to get these locations because I want to depict it onto a custom map of my own using Javascript (which I have also never used before). Any kind of help would be extremely helpful!

Comment: +1 for an interesting problem

Comment: haha thanks. its driving me insane, thats for sure

Comment: In which environment do you want to find that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diving a bit into the source code you'll quickly find http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/js/maps.js, and there you can see that the positions are loaded from http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/stations/bikeStations.xml.

You also might have found that using the Network tracker in your browser's debugging console.

Comment: Thank yooooou! You have no idea how much time this just saved me.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/stations/bikeStations.xml

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a million :D Just curious, how did you find it? Cuz I was looking for some type of xml file like this that would have the info on there.
EDIT: Just saw the comment underneath this one that explains how it was found. Thanks again!

Comment: This XML is the API for all bikeshare apps. Check http://bikes.oobrien.com/?city=washingtondc